# pages won't be loaded in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

After reaching the home page I got this page missing css script , is this related to permissions or what

any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please first delete var and generated and static folder using below command except .htaccess after run provided the below command list.

If not render proper page then you can change in .htaccess file as below.

```
## Enable rewrites

    ##Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine on

sudo rm -rf pub/static sudo rm -rf var/cache sudo rm -rf var/composer_home sudo rm -rf var/generation sudo rm -rf var/page_cache sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed sudo rm -rf var/log

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

I hope it's help to you.